# Make HTML/CSS Breadcrumbs Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a breadcrumb code I wish to use on my site, but it is not responsive. Any ideas on how to get this to scale down properly with the page as it goes into mobile view? Right now it breaks itself apart into several lines as the resolution is reduced.

Thanks for any help!

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb { 
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.breadcrumb li { 
    float: left; 
}
.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
    background: 004aa1;                   /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(166, 80%, 36%, 1.0); 
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(166, 80%, 36%, 1.0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}   
.breadcrumb li a:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
}   
.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(166, 80%, 26%, 1.0); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(166, 80%, 26%, 1.0); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(166, 80%, 16%, 1.0); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(166, 80%, 16%, 1.0); }

.breadcrumb li a:hover { background: hsla(166, 80%, 10%, 1.0); }
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: hsla(166, 80%, 10%, 1.0) !important; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Equipment</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead of break into separate lines?

Comment: Use media queries to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries.

```
@media all and(max-width:500px){
     .breadcrumb{
          font-size: 10px;
     }
     .breadcrumb li a{
          padding:10px 0 10px 30px;
     }
}
```

Paste this below your current code. What this means is that if the viewport drops below 500px, it will use this new block.

Also make sure you have this in your `<head>` tag, or else media queries will not behave properly.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 1):

You could use table table-cell but that doesn't necessarily fix your whole problem:

```
.breadcrumb { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.breadcrumb li { 
    display:table-cell; 
}
.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
    background: 004aa1;                   /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(166, 80%, 36%, 1.0); 
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
}
```

Using floats like you are, if it's breaking into lines that means your content is too big for that size. Using table/table-cell may keep them on a line but they could end up breaking their cells and looking awful, so you might want to break these down yourself:

```
.breadcrumb { display:block; }
.breadcrumb li { display:block; }

@media (min-width:769px){
    .breadcrumb { display:table; }
    .breadcrumb li { display:table-cell; }
}
```

I am also guessing a big part of your size issue is setting 55px left padding on each of your breadcrumbs, you could maybe drop that using media queries as well.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2761yow/)